# Qual è il significato di "scegliere" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Argon* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Alla sua morte, i figli e le nuore si dedicarono per settimane, con sgomento e ribrezzo, a **scegliere** la montagna di relitti domestici da cui l’alloggio era invaso: Nona Màlia aveva conservato, indiscriminatamente, robe raffinate e pattume rivoltante.

Ho letto tutte le accezioni del verbo "scegliere" sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scegliere) e sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* ([[1](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00916.jpg)] e [[2](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00917.jpg)]), ma non mi sembra che l'uso che ne fa l'autore in questa frase corrisponda a nessuna di queste. Intuisco, però, che ha a che vedere con il fatto che in quella "montagna di relitti" c'erano oggetti di valore e che  i figli e le nuore di nona Màlia  dovevano cercarceli accuratamente.

Per questa ragione vi chiedo: cosa intendeva Levi con "scegliere" nel testo?

Comment: Credo ti possa aiutare anche la [Crusca](http://www.lessicografia.it/Controller?lemma=SCEGLIERE_e_SCERRE&rewrite=1), _Definizione: Cernere, Separare, o Mettere di per se, cose di qualità diversa, per distinguerle, o per eleggerne il migliore; e talvolta Elegger semplicemente._ Dal Grande dizionario della lingua italiana la [6]. Potrebbe anche voler dire che figli e nuore si prendono tutta la montagna di relitti domestici, ma non a caso, scegliendo ognuno le cose che vuole... ma devi vedere dal contesto.

Answer (score 1):

In realtà va abbastanza bene la prima definizione nel link che hai allegato:

> Distinguere in un gruppo, in una varietà di cose o, anche all'interno di una categoria e prenderne fuori materialmente o considerare a parte ciò che risulta dotato delle caratteristiche che hanno ispirato la scelta, o che appare migliore o più idoneo a un uso, a una destinazione, al raggiungimento di uno scopo.

Oppure la definizione 2 del Treccani:

> Prendere la parte migliore da un insieme di cose o da una quantità di materiale, separandola dalla parte meno buona, o più scadente, o inutile:

Nella frase in oggetto significa che i personaggi hanno setacciato *"la montagna di relitti domestici da cui l’alloggio era invaso"* alla ricerca di quello che valeva la pena tenere.

Comment: Quello che mi sembra strano è che qui è "scegliere la montagna di relitti domestici", cioè, non si sta dicendo che si sta prendendo una parte di questa montagna di relitti, come si fa negli esempi che appaiono in questa accezione: "Le si­gnore si fermano dinnanzi  alle vetrine, entrano nelle bot­teghe,  guardano attentamente tutte le novità,  discutono e scelgono. Scelgono le primizie;  hanno  bisogno  di  ravvi­vare il  loro  appartamento  con  qualche  mobile  curioso  e raro" (D'Annunzio). De tutte le cose  che trovano nelle botteghe, selezionano "le promizie".

Comment: O, nell'esempio del Treccani, "scegliere i funghi tra quelli non velenosi", si prendono alcuni funghi dell'insieme di funghi non velenosi. Ma qui non si prendono l'intera montagna di relitti domestici.

Comment: @Charo prendo questo esempio che calza con la definizione 2 del Treccani: se dico che sto "scegliendo la frutta" non sto dicendo che sto scegliendo tra la frutta OPPURE qualcos'altro, ma che sto separando la frutta migliore dalla peggiore. Ed è quello che succede nel racconto che hai indicato: stanno dividendo nella "montagna" di roba le cose da buttare e quelle da tenere. Si dice anche "Scegliere l'insalata" nel senso di buttare via le foglie avvizzite.

Comment: Sì, ma quando dico "sceglio la frutta" sto selezionando frutta da un insieme o, come hai detto, separando la frutta migliore dalla peggiore. 
Ma in "scegliere la montagna di relitti domestici" non ha senso selezionare la montagna di relitti. Devo capire che quello che si seleziona, che si separa sono i relitti? Cioè, l'espressione vorrebbe dire "scegliere i relitti da tutta quella montagna di relitti domestici" nel senso di selezionare quelli che valeva la pena tenere?

Comment: @Charo Sinceramente non vedo differenze tra *scegliere la frutta* e *scegliere la montagna di relitti domestici*. Sono entrambi nomi collettivi.

Comment: Direi che la prima definizione c'entri poco (lì il complemento oggetto è la cosa migliore, più idonea etc.), mentre nel passo di Levi a quel che pare l'oggetto è _l'insieme all'interno del quale_ trovare la cosa migliore etc. La seconda definizione non è chiarissima, ma sembra più calzante; pare confermarlo anche lo Zingarelli (“2 prendere la parte migliore separandola da quella peggiore: scegliere la frutta, la lana; scegliere fior da fiore”). [segue]

Comment: [segue] Personalmente non credo di aver mai usato così il verbo “scegliere” (e fuori contesto penserei che “scegliere la frutta” significhi “...rispetto al dolce o al formaggio”), ma lo trovo comprensibile.

Comment: @egreg: La differenza che avverto io è che in "scegliere la frutta" si prende frutta o, nell'esempio del Treccani, in "scegliere i funghi" si prendono funghi, ma in "scegliere la montagna di relitti domestici", se il significato è quello spiegato nella risposta, non si prende la montagna di relitti. Invece, "scegliere i relitti domestici" mi sembra simile a "scegliere la frutta": immagino che l'espressione del testo vada interpretata così.